# How can I display data time in this format:20180304

Tags: java

I have this string:

```
private String dataTime = "2018-03-04";
```

How can I display it in YYYYMMDD format, e.g. 20180304?

Many thanks!

Comment: you simply need to remove the `-` occurences. use `String.replace`. See here `https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/String.html`

Comment: Simply replacing the hyphen with String replace will give you the behaviour you want but it might be worth considering using date formatters that will enable you to support multiple formats.

Comment: if you need to use a date formatter, search "java date format" in Google

Answer (score 2):

String replaceall:

```
String s = "2018-03-04";
s = s.replaceAll("-","");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows

```
String dataTime="2018-03-04"; 
String result = dataTime.replaceAll("-","");
```